# JSR223 script to point to file location throws error

Tags: jmeter, jsr223

i have added JSR223 pre-processor to point to the file that needs to be picked by the http request. when i run the request in a loop, it needs to pick different file each time so, the file location is bit complicated. So, i tried something like below:
[filePath in JSR223](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x6ONK.png)

But, this throws an error. should i be using two back slash? that throws error too.

I am getting the folder in the project location by using:

${__BeanShell(import org.apache.jmeter.services.FileServer; FileServer.getFileServer().getBaseDir();)}\FileToUpload\

But, i need to go to different folders on each thread hence the complicated way to get the file through JSR223 script. Is there a easier way?

Answer (score 0):

1. First of all [starting from JMeter 3.1 you're supposed to be using JSR223 Test Elements](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) and [Groovy language](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black/) so consider migrating to [__groovy() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy)
2. Second you need to use **triple slashes** because you need to:

   - escape each backslash in Java strings with another backslash
   - third backslash is to handle JMeter Functions escape meta character (for example if your function contains comma you need to escape it with the backslash like `\,`

     ```
     ${__groovy(org.apache.jmeter.services.FileServer.getFileServer().getBaseDir() + '\\\Test Plan.jmx',)}
     ```

   Alternatively you can use forward slashes:

   ```
   ${__groovy(org.apache.jmeter.services.FileServer.getFileServer().getBaseDir() + '/Test Plan.jmx',)}
   ```

   or go for [file.separator property](https://www.journaldev.com/851/java-file-separator-separatorchar-pathseparator-pathseparatorchar)

   ```
   ${__groovy(org.apache.jmeter.services.FileServer.getFileServer().getBaseDir() + System.getProperty('file.separator') + 'Test Plan.jmx',)}
   ```